# Not getting a response from my variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a live chat app. I am currently working on sending data from the signup page. I  am expecting the code below to give me a response that reads the data I inputed.
I tried to change the capital letters in ("INPUT") but it didn't work.

```
function _(element) {

  return document.getElementById(element);
}

var signup_button = _("signup_button");
signup_button.addEventListener("click", collect_data);

function collect_data() {

  var myform = _("myform");
  var inputs = myform.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

  var data = {};
  for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    var key = inputs[i].name;

    switch (key) {

      case "username":
        data.username = inputs[i].value;
        break;

      case "email":
        data.email = inputs[i].value;
        break;

      case "gender":
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
          data.gender = inputs[i].value;
        }
        break;

      case "password":
        data.password = inputs[i].value;
        break;

      case "password2":
        data.password2 = inputs[i].value;
        break;

    }
  }

  send_data(data, "signup");
}

function send_data(data) {

  var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xml.onload = function() {

    if (xml.readyState == 4 || xml.status == 200) {

      alert(xml.responseText);
    }

    data.data_type = type;
    var data_string = JSON.stringify(data);

    xml.open("POST", "api.php", true);
    xml.send(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: you're using XMLHttpRequest all wrong ... you can't open/send inside the onload handler, since the onload handler won't run until you've opened and sent a request

Comment: i.e. you're not getting a response since you are not even sending a request

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I ended the xml.onload loop before opening and sending the request and it worked.